# Should we refer recommendations and open questions to BGG and Reddit?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Once in a while someone asks a recommendation/open question.  The answer they get is "we don't do recommendation/open question" + closing the question.  To me that feels too harsh.

I think a better answer would be: "we don't do recommendations/open questions, a good place for those questions is BGG/Reddit/others?"

Here is the latest example:
[which framework for an online mulitplayer boardgame](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/58385/which-framework-for-an-online-mulitplayer-boardgame)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think we should do that as a formal policy but members are free to make a suggestion of where a question can better be answered. I think overall we should focus on the question being on or off topic and just let people point to offsite resources as needed.

And honestly the question you linked to seems more of a programming question on how to implement things in a digital game then a gaming question.